# My matrix multiplication function is returning blank or incorrect outputs

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication

The function I've written to  multiply matrices is not properly out putting or is giving me a blank one. It managed to give me one correct output though I can't get find that array anymore.

When I inputted
     `int[][] test = new int[][]{
      {2, 4},
      {5, 3},
      {3, 5}
    };
    int[][] test2 = new int[][]{
      {3, 4, 2},
      {5, 1, 2}
};`
It's return an array of zeros

````
    int[][] toRet = new int[arr1.length][arr2[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < arr2[0].length; j++){
        for(int k = 02; k < arr1[0].length; k++){
          toRet[i][j] += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
        }
      }
    }

    return toRet;
  }```  

It worked for a minute and I didn't change anything but my test.
````

Comment: k = 02 in 3rd loop, why not k=0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 3rd loop is wrong. You initialized k with 2, it should be k=0. Now taking your
example. Your matrix is

```
int[][] test = new int[][]{
      {2, 4},
      {5, 3},
      {3, 5}
    };
```

**arr1[0].length** will return 2 as there are 2 elements only and **k < arr1[0].length** will return false. So your 3rd loop will exit without any summation and multiplications. That is why you are getting all elements 0.
Change your 3rd loop to k=0, which looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < arr2[0].length; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < arr1[0].length; k++){
          toRet[i][j] += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes Thank you. That was a stupid mistake that I missed. Sorry for bringing dumb things.